When using semantic versioning Launch4J throws error 'project.version' is in invalid format. Regex pattern: ^((\d(.)?)*\d+)(-\w+)?$
Using Launch4j-Maven-Plugin Version 2.5.0
When using the semantic versioning scheme https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html
Example: 1.0.0-alpha+001 throws error
'project.version' is in invalid format. Regex pattern: ^((\d(.)?)*\d+)(-\w+)?$
Because for some reason Launch4J checks the project.version against it's hardcoded regex even when fileVersion, txtFileVersion, productVersion, txtProductVersion are set manually.
All in a Launch4j conform format of x.x.x.x
I created this entry because on my search I could not find a solution on stackoverflow
Sorry ahead of time if I overlooked something
But I hope this can help someone else who faces a similar problem

I found the solution by checking all execution configuration options and finally found : disableVersionInfoDefaults
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>l4j-clui</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>launch4j</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                
            <disableVersionInfoDefaults>true</disableVersionInfoDefaults> 
                <!-- More config -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

which fixes the problem
